# Android Application and Code licensing

Tags: android, android-ndk

I don't understand the opensource and android licensing.

Say if i develop an application in android(which is open source Apache license), do i have to release the source code of my app as well? or should i write wrappers for my app, to that part which links with Android say activity / intent and many thousand other apis? Isn't this too tedious.

I'm greatly confused. If i have some proprietary piece of software / engine which i link it with android  libraries and have my application as top layer implemented as activity. do i have to release the source code?

Any pointers / reference to links would be helpful to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not mean you have to release your source code, the licence governs Android not your code, even if you modified the android source code you are not obliged to release it to everybody. See here: http://source.android.com/source/licenses.html and here: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.

It is a different matter if you modify the linux kernel which is under GPLv2, see here: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/COPYING